# Configuration incomplete while building prism launcher

Tags: qt, cmake

im trying to build prism launcher for windows on a linux machine using this instructions:
https://prismlauncher.org/wiki/development/build-instructions/

im getting this error. heres the log:

```
amiroof@amiroofPC:~/Games/PrismLauncher-Cracked$ cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DENABLE_LTO=ON -DLauncher_QT_VERSION_MAJOR=6 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/amiroof/Qt/6.4.0/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake
-- IPO / LTO will only be enabled for release builds
-- Using bundled ECM
-- Git commit: 6b2346a363ecbd1fab59cdd717a59e0661454796
-- Git tag: -128-NOTFOUND
-- Git refspec: refs/heads/develop
-- Checking for one of the modules 'scdoc'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:311 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    KDEInstallDirs


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:323 (install):
  install FILES given no DESTINATION!


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:324 (install):
  install FILES given no DESTINATION!


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:326 (install):
  install FILES given no DESTINATION!


-- Using system zlib
-- Using bundled QuaZip
-- Using Qt version 6
-- Using bundled tomlplusplus
-- Using bundled ghc_filesystem
-- System name: Linux
-- Compiler ID: GNU
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES: cxx_std_98;cxx_template_template_parameters;cxx_std_11;cxx_alias_templates;cxx_alignas;cxx_alignof;cxx_attributes;cxx_auto_type;cxx_constexpr;cxx_decltype;cxx_decltype_incomplete_return_types;cxx_default_function_template_args;cxx_defaulted_functions;cxx_defaulted_move_initializers;cxx_delegating_constructors;cxx_deleted_functions;cxx_enum_forward_declarations;cxx_explicit_conversions;cxx_extended_friend_declarations;cxx_extern_templates;cxx_final;cxx_func_identifier;cxx_generalized_initializers;cxx_inheriting_constructors;cxx_inline_namespaces;cxx_lambdas;cxx_local_type_template_args;cxx_long_long_type;cxx_noexcept;cxx_nonstatic_member_init;cxx_nullptr;cxx_override;cxx_range_for;cxx_raw_string_literals;cxx_reference_qualified_functions;cxx_right_angle_brackets;cxx_rvalue_references;cxx_sizeof_member;cxx_static_assert;cxx_strong_enums;cxx_thread_local;cxx_trailing_return_types;cxx_unicode_literals;cxx_uniform_initialization;cxx_unrestricted_unions;cxx_user_literals;cxx_variadic_macros;cxx_variadic_templates;cxx_std_14;cxx_aggregate_default_initializers;cxx_attribute_deprecated;cxx_binary_literals;cxx_contextual_conversions;cxx_decltype_auto;cxx_digit_separators;cxx_generic_lambdas;cxx_lambda_init_captures;cxx_relaxed_constexpr;cxx_return_type_deduction;cxx_variable_templates;cxx_std_17;cxx_std_20;cxx_std_23
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/amiroof/Games/PrismLauncher-Cracked/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

and here's the CMakeOutput.log file:https://easyupload.io/jrp5db

**EDIT:** i install extra-cmake-modules and the prev error got fixed but now im getting this one:

```
 amiroof@amiroofPC:~/Games/PrismLauncher-Cracked$ sudo cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DENABLE_LTO=ON -DLauncher_QT_VERSION_MAJOR=6 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/amiroof/Qt/6.4.0/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake
-- IPO / LTO will only be enabled for release builds
-- Git commit: 6b2346a363ecbd1fab59cdd717a59e0661454796
-- Git tag: -128-NOTFOUND
-- Git refspec: refs/heads/develop
-- Checking for one of the modules 'scdoc'
CMake Warning at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMQueryQt.cmake:97 (message):
  Failed call: "QT_INSTALL_PREFIX"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs6.cmake:201 (ecm_query_qt)
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs.cmake:15 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:311 (include)


CMake Error at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMQueryQt.cmake:98 (message):
  Qt6 qtpaths call failed: Permission denied
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs6.cmake:201 (ecm_query_qt)
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs.cmake:15 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:311 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/amiroof/Games/PrismLauncher-Cracked/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: @Tsyvarev i did clone the submodules.

Comment: Well, the first error message you got - `include could not find requested file` - is because in the case `Using bundled ECM` they add to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable only `modules` subdirectory of extra-cmake-modules, while should also add `find-modules` and `kde-modules` subdirectories: https://github.com/PrismLauncher/PrismLauncher/blob/6b2346a363ecbd1fab59cdd717a59e0661454796/CMakeLists.txt#L108. In case non-bundled ECM they add `ECM_MODULE_PATH` variable, which contains all needed subdirectories.

Comment: @Tsyvarev read the edit. i actually fixed the first error but im getting a different one now.

Comment: The second error (`Qt6 qtpaths call failed`) is about running `qtpaths --query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX`. (Full path to the `qtpaths` executable is contained in `QUERY_EXECUTABLE` cache variable, which you can find in the `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory). You could try to run this command manually and check whether it fails or not. BTW. the `sudo` in the second case looks suspicious: normally, CMake projects are configured from the normal user, without root privileges.

Comment: @Tsyvarev when i run `qtpaths --query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX` i get a `qtpaths: could not find a Qt installation of ''` message. i tried running it in the build folder and in the PrismLauncher folder.

Comment: Have you installed all QT6 packages which noted in the build instructions? (`qt6-base-dev qtchooser qt6-base-dev-tools libqt6core6 libqt6core5compat6-dev libqt6network6`). BTW, instead of just referencing the build instructions you use, it is better to add to the **question post** your **actual steps**. E.g. the instruction explicitly tells about installing `extra-cmake-modules`, but your initial attempt was without that package.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i installed them and nothing changed.